# First chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred

Tags: kentico

I am using Kentico in my project. 
Client asked to upgrade the version of kentico from 7 to 9.
I downloaded the nuget package and updated all the references of CMS i.e. Kentico to that of version 9.

But since doing that
when I execute the project, I am getting an exception.

> Could not load file or assembly 'CMS.DataEngine, Version=9.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=834b12a258f213f9' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)":"CMS.DataEngine, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=834b12a258f213f9

`CMS.DataEngine` is already added to the references.
I have already tried all the solutions to this type of exception from other questions that were posted earlier but no progress.

Comment: did you follow this steps in this order? 1. Upgrade 7 to 8 (https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Upgrading+Kentico+7+to+8) 
2. Upgrade 8 to 8.1 (https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Upgrading+to+Kentico+8.1)
3. Upgrade 8.1 to 8.2 (https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Upgrading+to+Kentico+8.2)
4. Upgrade 8.2 to 9 (https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Upgrading+to+Kentico+9)

Answer (score 3):

This is not the proper way to upgrade Kentico instance. First thing to note is you need to upgrade through all versions. That means you need to go like this:

> 7 -> 8
>
> 8 -> 8.1
>
> 8.1 -> 8.2
>
> 8.2 -> 9

You can use Kentico installation manager (KIM) to upgrade Kentico. This upgrade updates both **database** and **project files/dlls** to given version. After you upgrade it is absolutely **essential** that you run your site because there is a script that is executed first time you run Kentico after upgrade. This script needs to update few things in the database as well - you cannot skip this step.

Once you have Kentico backend upgraded you can upgrade your MVC application by updating NuGet package to a newer version (assuming you are using MVC application which is not clear from your question).

You can also check out official documentation for upgrade between each Kentico version. Eg. [this](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Upgrading+Kentico+7+to+8) covers upgrade from 7 to 8